# Multidimensional array - Print only specific key value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here is the output of my program  `var_dump($myvar):`

```
f_shopping array(2) {
["product-size"]=> array(3) {
    [۰]=> object(WP_Term)#20766 (11) {
        ["term_id"]=> int(45) 
        ["name"]=> string(8) "Large" 
        ["slug"]=> string(5) "l" 
        ["term_group"]=> int(0) 
        ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(45) 
        ["taxonomy"]=> string(13) "pa_product-size" 
        ["description"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["parent"]=> int(0) 
        ["count"]=> int(2) 
        ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" 
        ["meta_value"]=> string(1) "0" 
    } 
    [۱]=> object(WP_Term)#20791 (11) {
        ["term_id"]=> int(47) 
        ["name"]=> string(8) "Small" 
        ["slug"]=> string(5) "s" 
        ["term_group"]=> int(0) 
        ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(47) 
        ["taxonomy"]=> string(13) "pa_product-size" 
        ["description"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["parent"]=> int(0) 
        ["count"]=> int(2) 
        ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" 
        ["meta_value"]=> string(1) "0" 
    } 
    [۲]=> object(WP_Term)#20780 (11) { 
        ["term_id"]=> int(46) 
        ["name"]=> string(10) "Medium" 
        ["slug"]=> string(6) "m" 
        ["term_group"]=> int(0) 
        ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(46) 
        ["taxonomy"]=> string(13) "pa_product-size" 
        ["description"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["parent"]=> int(0) 
        ["count"]=> int(2) 
        ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" 
        ["meta_value"]=> string(1) "0" 
    } 
} 
["shopping-pack"]=> array(4) {
    [۰]=> object(WP_Term)#20751 (11) {
        ["term_id"]=> int(26) 
        ["name"]=> string(13) "Box" 
        ["slug"]=> string(3) "b" 
        ["term_group"]=> int(0) ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(26) 
        ["taxonomy"]=> string(16) "pa_shopping-pack" 
        ["description"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["parent"]=> int(0) 
        ["count"]=> int(1) 
        ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" 
        ["meta_value"]=> string(1) "1" 
    }
    [۱]=> object(WP_Term)#20750 (11) {
        ["term_id"]=> int(25) 
        ["name"]=> string(12) "Kilos" 
        ["slug"]=> string(4) "k" 
        ["term_group"]=> int(0) 
        ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(25) 
        ["taxonomy"]=> string(16) "pa_shopping-pack" 
        ["description"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["parent"]=> int(0) ["count"]=> int(1) 
        ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" 
        ["meta_value"]=> string(1) "2" 
    } 
    [۲]=> object(WP_Term)#20749 (11) {
        ["term_id"]=> int(24) 
        ["name"]=> string(13) "Single" 
        ["slug"]=> string(6) "s" 
        ["term_group"]=> int(0) 
        ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(24) 
        ["taxonomy"]=> string(16) "pa_shopping-pack" 
        ["description"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["parent"]=> int(0) 
        ["count"]=> int(2) 
        ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" 
        ["meta_value"]=> string(1) "3" 
    }
    [۳]=> object(WP_Term)#20748 (11) { 
        ["term_id"]=> int(73) 
        ["name"]=> string(13) "Packed" 
        ["slug"]=> string(6) "p" 
        ["term_group"]=> int(0) 
        ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(73) 
        ["taxonomy"]=> string(16) "pa_shopping-pack" 
        ["description"]=> string(0) "" 
        ["parent"]=> int(0) 
        ["count"]=> int(1) 
        ["filter"]=> string(3) "raw" 
        ["meta_value"]=> string(1) "4" 
    }
}
```

How can i store all ["name"]s inside of ["product-size"] and ["shopping-pack"] in two separate simple arrays with the values of "slug" as key and "name" as value?

I've searched before and tried. the solutions didn't work.

Comment: e.g.: foreach($myarr as $a){ echo $a['name'];}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `array_column`

```
$product = array_column($myVar['product-size'],'name','slug');
print_r($product);

$shopping = array_column($myVar['shopping-pack'],'name','slug');
print_r($shopping);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this help to you:

```html
$arr = "your array output";
$count_prod = count($arr['f_shopping']['product-size']);
$count_shopp = count($arr['f_shopping']['shopping-pack']);
$newArray = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < $count_prod; $i++) {
 $slug = $arr['f_shopping']['product-size'][$i]['slug'];
 $name = $arr['f_shopping']['product-size'][$i]['name'];
 $newArray[]($slug -> $name);
}
for ($i = 0; $i < $count_shopp; $i++) {
 $slug = $arr['f_shopping']['shopping-pack'][$i]['slug'];
 $name = $arr['f_shopping']['shopping-pack'][$i]['name'];
 $newArray[]($slug -> $name);
}

print_r($newArray);
```